# Trying to install AWSCLI on top of JNLP slave Docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am relatively new to docker, I have a base image from https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkins/jnlp-slave/4.7-1-jdk11/images/sha256-b93b836b2d4f59f027106e3991ed1e777dc092d8feec2c56f29214201d6c2322?context=explore

And on top of that I am trying to add a few utilities, which include awscli, I have tried numerous ways from using the `USER jenkins` directive to `chown` with no effect, the aws cli gets always installed into `/usr/local/bin` under root and when Jenkins user tries to access it, its not found / permission denied. I have also tried installation with the `-i` and `-b` directives with no effect!

Below is my docker file:

```
ADD file:575bf0d00d72810609a4118728923f11625b43de536352fe69a341086e4ebfd1 in / 
ENV TZ=Asia/Singapore
COPY * /home/jenkins/.ssh/
USER root
RUN pwd
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates apt-transport-https wget curl
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - && apt-get update && apt-get install google-cloud-sdk kubectl -y
RUN apt install vim -y
COPY /helm /usr/local/bin/helm
RUN helm init --client-only --skip-refresh
RUN helm repo rm stable
RUN helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt update && apt install rsync -y --no-install-recommends && chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins/.ssh/ -R && chmod 700 /home/jenkins/.ssh -R && chmod 400 /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa*
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.kube/ && chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins/.kube/ -R
RUN apt-get install -y jq
### Lines in this block are for Dev K8s Jenkins image. Optional and can be commented out for other environments ###
RUN apt install -y python3-pip && pip3 install Jinja2 && pip3 install jinja2-cli
RUN pip3 install yq
RUN wget https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/releases/download/v0.119.1/helmfile_linux_amd64 && chmod +x helmfile_linux_amd64 && mv helmfile_linux_amd64 /usr/local/bin/helmfile
### End of block ###
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
RUN npm install -g newman && npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra && npm install -g newman-reporter-junitfull
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/aws-cli && chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins/aws-cli -R && cd /home/jenkins/ && curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install -i /home/jenkins/aws-cli -b /home/jenkins/aws-cli/bin && export PATH="/home/jenkins/aws-cli/bin:$PATH" && chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins/aws-cli -R


USER jenkins
ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-agent"]
```

I simply want the jenkins user to be able to run the aws cli commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the AWS CLI is installed and accessible to the Jenkins user within the Docker image. Try this:

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-slave:4.7-1-jdk11

USER root

ENV TZ=Asia/Singapore

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates apt-transport-https wget curl jq

# Install Google Cloud SDK
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install google-cloud-sdk kubectl -y

# Install other utilities
RUN apt-get install -y vim rsync

# Install Helm
COPY helm /usr/local/bin/helm
RUN helm init --client-only --skip-refresh && \
    helm repo rm stable && \
    helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable

# Set the timezone
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install additional dependencies for Dev K8s Jenkins image
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip && pip3 install Jinja2 jinja2-cli yq && \
    wget https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/releases/download/v0.119.1/helmfile_linux_amd64 && \
    chmod +x helmfile_linux_amd64 && \
    mv helmfile_linux_amd64 /usr/local/bin/helmfile

# Install Node.js and Newman
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install -g newman newman-reporter-htmlextra newman-reporter-junitfull

# Install AWS CLI for Jenkins user
USER jenkins

RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/aws-cli && \
    cd /home/jenkins/ && \
    curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install -i /home/jenkins/aws-cli -b /home/jenkins/aws-cli/bin && \
    echo 'export PATH="/home/jenkins/aws-cli/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-agent"]
```

Comment: I had tried this before but it still does not work, I copied this docker fiel also exactly, but still the awscli is installed as root in /usr/local/bin

Comment: Can you try adding this:

RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/aws-cli && \
    cd /home/jenkins/ && \
    curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install -i /home/jenkins/aws-cli -b /home/jenkins/aws-cli/bin && \
    echo 'export PATH="/home/jenkins/aws-cli/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
    chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins/aws-cli

ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-agent"]